# webpack-dev-server with backend configuration

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using webpack-dev-server for an angularjs app on localhost:8081
Also i use tomcat server on port 8080.
I have next structure

```
project/
project/src/main/sources/
project/src/main/sources/css
project/src/main/sources/js
project/src/main/sources/img
project/src/main/sources/styles
project/src/main/sources/views
project/src/main/sources/index.html
project/src/main/sources/js

webapp/
webapp/build/
webapp/build/js/bundle.js
webapp/build/js/bundle.js.map
webapp/build/js/jquery.min.js
```

I have next index.html:

....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

....

I have next webpack condig

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "\\src\\main\\sources",
    entry: ["./index.js",
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081'],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "\\src\\main\\webapp\\build\\js\\",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "\\js\\"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel", query: { presets: ['es2015'] }},
            {test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw"}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: __dirname + "\\src\\main\\sources",
        publicPath: '/js/',
        port: 8081,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        proxy: {
            '/somePath' : 'http://localhost:8080/'
        }
    }
};
```

So when i open http://localhost:8081/webpack-dev-server/js/bundle I see "HOT" bundle.
With this configuration: css styles, img doesn't obtained from localhost:8081, but it related with webpack, and i need to recompile this too. How to change config?

Also i have a lot of different request to server side like:

```
"localhost:8081/someRequest1/some", 
"localhost:8081/someRequest2/some", 
......
"localhost:8081/someRequest1/some"
```

I can't write each request in proxy settings, with witch settings in configuratuin it will work?
I tried

```
proxy: {
            '*' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
            '/js/*': '/'
        }
```

With this config js/bundle not found. 
Also i tried

```
proxy: {
            '*' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
            '/js/*': '/'
        }
```

and

```
proxy: {
            '*' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
            '/js/*': 'http://localhost:8081/'
        }
```

js/bundle not working too.

UPDATE 1.
Probably I need proxy all requests except /js/. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a pattern, ie:

```
proxy: {
        '/api/v1/*' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    }
```

or simply

```
proxy: {
        '/api/*' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
    }
```

This requires you to update your api to follow this behaviour.

Comment: "localhost:8081/someRequest1/some" not muched with "/api/*"
Since I have a lot of request from root like "/someRequest101/some" I can't write all to proxy config.